# MySQL How to limit amount of rows from JOIN-Query only from first Table and not the Second Table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, join

I have a two Tables one with Countries and second with Cities.

First Table is Countries

country_id | country_name

Second Table is Cities

country_id | city_id | city_name

I want to limit  amount of queries from second Table to 3 Cities. Because one Country have a lot of Cities. I need only 5 Cities.

My Query:

```
$query = “SELECT c.country_name, p.city_name FROM (SELECT * FROM Cities LIMIT 3) AS p LEFT JOIN Countries as c ON p.county_id = c.county_id”;ter code here

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

$my_array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc){
 array_push($my_array, $row);
}
```

If I fill $my_array i get 3 results from Database

My output:

[0] => Array
    (
        [country_name] => Country 1
        [city_name] => City 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [country_name] => Country 1
        [city_name] => City 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [country_name] => Country 1
        [city_name] => City 3
    )

I need something like this

```
County 1
-----------------------
City 1 of Country 1
City 2 of Country 1
City 3 of Country 1
City 4 of Country 1
City 5 of Country 1

County 2
-----------------------
City 1 of Country 2
City 2 of Country 2
City 3 of Country 2
City 4 of Country 2
City 5 of Country 2

County 3
-----------------------
City 1 of Country 3
City 2 of Country 3
City 3 of Country 3
City 4 of Country 3
City 5 of Country 3
```

What I do wrong? I use MySQL 5.6.26

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
SELECT city_id, city_name FROM Cities AS p LEFT JOIN Countries AS c ON c.country_id = p.country_id WHERE c.country_id = 'id' LIMIT 0,5
```